# How I can access Class method variable in instance method OR Use a common variable for both?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, sprite-kit, instance

I have this Class method to create a hero object.

```
+(id)hero
{
    NSArray *heroWalkingFrames;
    //Setup the array to hold the walking frames
    NSMutableArray *walkFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    //Load the TextureAtlas for the hero
    SKTextureAtlas *heroAnimatedAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"HeroImages"];
    //Load the animation frames from the TextureAtlas
    int numImages = (int)heroAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count;
    for (int i=1; i <= numImages/2; i++) {
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hero%d", i];
        SKTexture *temp = [heroAnimatedAtlas textureNamed:textureName];
        [walkFrames addObject:temp];
    }
    heroWalkingFrames = walkFrames;
    //Create hero sprite, setup position in middle of the screen, and add to Scene
    SKTexture *temp = heroWalkingFrames[0];

    Hero *hero = [Hero spriteNodeWithTexture:temp];
    hero.name =@"Hero";
    hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:hero.size];
    hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = heroCategory;
    hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory | groundCategory | homeCategory;    
    return hero;
}
```

and I have another instance method to perform run animation for my hero.

```
-(void)Start
{
        SKAction *incrementRight = [SKAction moveByX:10 y:0 duration:.05];
        SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction repeatActionForever:incrementRight];
        [self runAction:moveRight];     
}
```

now  `heroWalkingFrames` variable in `Start` method so I can perform animation, I want to add this line in `Start` method

```
 [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:heroWalkingFrames timePerFrame:0.1f resize:NO restore:YES]];
```

Is there any way I can use this variable for both ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, in `Hero.h` add:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *walkingFrames;
```

Then, in your `+(id)hero` method, instead of declaring a new array `NSArray *heroWalkingFrames`, use:

```
+(id)hero
{
    //Setup the array to hold the walking frames
    NSMutableArray *walkFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    //Load the TextureAtlas for the hero
    SKTextureAtlas *heroAnimatedAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"HeroImages"];
    //Load the animation frames from the TextureAtlas
    int numImages = (int)heroAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count;
    for (int i=1; i <= numImages/2; i++) {
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hero%d", i];
        SKTexture *temp = [heroAnimatedAtlas textureNamed:textureName];
        [walkFrames addObject:temp];
    }

    //We set hero texture to the first animation texture:
    Hero *hero = [Hero spriteNodeWithTexture:walkFrames[0]];
    // Set the hero property "walkingFrames"
    hero.walkingFrames = walkFrames;

    hero.name =@"Hero";
    hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:hero.size];
    hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = heroCategory;
    hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory | groundCategory | homeCategory;    
    return hero;
}
```

Comment: ` Hero *hero = [Hero spriteNodeWithTexture:temp]; ` what is temp here ? I have to write this line after temp is created

Comment: Yeah I noticed that just after submitting the answer. Check again, I have edited it.

Comment: Delete that line, you don't need it anymore